# Thirsty vs thirstily

Tags: meaning, adjectives, adverbs

> I wandered in the desert thirsty.

> I thirstily wandered in the desert.

Which one is correct to describe “Being thirsty, I wandered in the desert.”?

Comment: A comma might make the first sentence easier to read: "I wandered in the desert, thirsty".

Answer (score 0):

“I wandered in the desert thirsty” means “I, a thirsty person, wandered in the desert.”

“I thirstily wandered in the desert” means “I wandered in a thirsty fashion in the desert.”

Both are grammatically correct, but as I do not know how anyone would “wander in a thirsty fashion”, I am guessing you mean the first.

Comment: In that context, I would interpret _thirstily_ figuratively, and imagine somebody eagerly hurrying round the desert looking for something intangible, such as solitude, beauty, or enlightenment.

Comment: Maybe you can wander thirstily if you are wandering specifically in search of water. Or maybe you have a metaphorical thirst for wandering.

Answer (score 0):

Neither is very good.  The adverb wants to describe how you wandered, does being thirsty change the way that you wander? I'm not sure that works very well.  Compare with "He eyed the cake hungrily". The adverb tells you how and why he was looking at the cake.

Using the adjective at the end isn't quite right either.  It should have the comma that shadowtalker suggests, but even then it is rather poetic in its mood.

Even your basic meaning "Being thirsy, I wandered in the desert" is somewhat odd.  It suggests to me that your thirst was a reason, not a cause of your wandering.  Not quite right...

So I'd probably drop back to "I wandered in the desert and became thirsty", or "My wandering in the desert made me thirsty".

In the acceptable "He eyed the cake" expression, you could put "hungrily" at the beginning, before "eyed", or after "cake".  All positions are valid.